# Assign a new value in list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x

I'm learning list comprehension and I was wondering if it's possible to assign a new value to a sub list.

```
newConfig = ['0', '0']

original = open("ciscoconf.txt", "r")

originalList = original.read().split("!") 

originalLen = len(originalLen) - 1 

for i in range(1, originalLen):
    originalList[i] = originalList[i].split("\n")

newConfig[0] = input(str("New IP"))

for i in range(originalLen):
    q = 0
    for k in originalList[i]:

        if k.find('ip address') == 0:
            originalList[i][q] = "ip address " + " ".join(newConfig)

        q += 1
```

Comment: I don't see a list comprehension in the code you posted. You should only use list comprehensions to construct new lists, not mutate existing lists. If you are going to mutate a list you should use a for loop.

Comment: That was my question. Thanks!